# How to wrap free text in a Stack Panel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know that if you type:

```
<StackPanel>
    Here is some text. It doesn't wrap.
</StackPanel>
```

XAML will wrap the text in a TextBlock and then display the new textblock in the StackPanel. However, the default TextBlock doesn't do text wrapping - you have to specifically tell it to.

So I tried to tell it to wrap by implicitly styling it:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDicionary>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
    Here is some reeeeeeaaaaally long text that is hopefully going to wrap.
</StackPanel>
```

But that didn't work.

Google recommends putting the text in a textblock manually like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Here is some manual Text"/>
</StackPanel>
```

But I like the simpler syntax of the first option - there must be a way tell it to wrap!  Any Ideas?

Comment: Your example with the implicit style does work if you put the text in a TextBlock, doesn't it? You can't add a string/text directly to a StackPanel without wrapping it in a TextBlock anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why the StackPanel is needed but I'll assume it is.

The first XAML fragment is not correct and cannot be executed.

StackPanels do not know about text formatting and strings cannot be inserted into a StackPanel as stated in the first XAML fragment. StackPanel arrange other controls not strings.

So to put text in a StackPanel the text has to be added to a control. There are several options:

1. TextBlock (very basic text formatting)
2. Label (very similar to a TextBlock with additional focus handling)
3. RichTextBox (more layout/markup options, editing, RTF format)
4. DocumentViewer (very rich text viewer XPS format)
5. WebBrowser (for displaying HTML)

As you mentioned the TextBlock will allow you to wrap the text and that is the simplest option that is available.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Erno de Weerd - knowing that StackPanels can't do add text natively put me on the right track.

I had simplified my problem to far. In reality, I had an ItemsControl with a StackPanel as it's ItemsPanelTemplate. Those can accept Text directly, because they wrap their input in a ContentControl before placing them in the ItemsPanelTemplate.  I overrode the PrepareContainerForItemOverride Function and it's good to go:

```
<CustomItemsPanel>
    <CustomItemsPanel.ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel/>
    </CustomItemsPanel.ItemsPanelTemplate>

    Here is some Free Floating Text

</CustomItemsPanel>
```

and then in the backend:

```
public class CustomItemsPanel : ItemsPanel
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        if(item is string str)
        {
            item = new TextBlock {Text=str, TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap};
        }

        return base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of overriding the PrepareContainerForItemOverride method you might want to consider implementing a DataTemplateSelector: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector that is a bit cleaner and allows all the styling to be done in XAML